# Android MediaPlayer use lot of resource

Tags: android, multithreading, service, audio

I'm making game in OpenGL 2.0 and I have problems with sounds, because sounds slow down my application and FPS decrease about 20 frames. I implement service for sounds and run it on new thread, but problem is same. MediaServer use more CPU than my application with lot of sprites.
I play only three sounds with total size less than 0.5 MB.
This is my code:

```
package com.filsoft.mouse;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Process;

public class Sound extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {
      private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
      private Looper mServiceLooper;
      private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    // Handler that receives messages from the thread
      private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
          MediaPlayer[] mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer[3];
          public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
              super(looper);
            mediaPlayer[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
            mediaPlayer[0].setLooping(true);

            mediaPlayer[1] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
            mediaPlayer[1].setLooping(true);

            mediaPlayer[2] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
            mediaPlayer[2].setLooping(true);
                try {
                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
mediaPlayer[i].prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


          }
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              play(msg.arg1);
          }
          public void stopAll()
          {
               if (mediaPlayer[0].isPlaying()) {
                      mediaPlayer[0].pause();
                    }
                    if (mediaPlayer[1].isPlaying()) {
                          mediaPlayer[1].pause();
                    }
                    if (mediaPlayer[2].isPlaying()) {
                          mediaPlayer[2].pause();
                    }
          }
          public void play(int idx)
          {
              stopAll();
              if (!mediaPlayer[idx].isPlaying()) {
                  mediaPlayer[idx].start();
                }
          }

      }

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("Audio",
                    Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            thread.start();

            // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
            mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
            mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);

        }
      public void startPlay(int idx)
      {
          Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
          msg.arg1 = idx;
          mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

      }
      public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
            public Sound getService() {
                return Sound.this;
            }

        }
      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        return START_STICKY;
      }

      public void onDestroy() {

      }

      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        stopSelf();
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple `MediaPlayer`s, you should use a [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) - a class specifically designed to play multiple streams simultaneously such as found in games. Looping sounds is also very easy:

> Sounds can be looped by setting a non-zero loop value. A value of -1 causes the sound to loop forever. In this case, the application must explicitly call the stop() function to stop the sound. Any other non-zero value will cause the sound to repeat the specified number of times, e.g. a value of 3 causes the sound to play a total of 4 times.

Comment: Yes but SoundPool have restriction, maximum 32 stream on PHONE not only my application and TOTAL SPACE 16mb, maybe my app and other opened apps cause overflow

Comment: Given that you're using 3 streams and you'll only be using those 3 in the foreground (when no other game/application can be in the foreground), you're expecting there will be a case where there are 30+ other streams running from other apps in the background, all playing sounds simultaneously with a higher priority than your sounds while a user is attempting to play your game?

Comment: Yes but my app is in developing stage. I think final product will have max 7-8 stream with total size about 1.5mb

Comment: So you think there will be a background app running over 24 simultaneous sounds while someone is playing your game? I don't think you're going to get a better way to play 7-8 sounds, particularly given that the MediaPlayer approach can't even do 3.

Comment: I have -12 error with Sound Pool but i load only 0.5 mb sounds?